# Java regex: Multiple delimiters preceded by "-"

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

Remove suffix from network name of hosts at specific delimiters preceded by "-"hyphen, so that if there are other combinations with "-", it should be taken as part of the network name.

Few examples:

```
abcd-new     --> abcd-new   ## Stays same ##
efgh-nic     --> efgh       ## delimiter is '-nic' ##
mnop-ilo-a   --> mnop-ilo   ## delimiter is '-a' ##
xyz-a01      --> xyz-a01   ## Stays same ##
vm-1-ad-nic  --> vm-1-ad    ## delimiter is '-nic' ##
vm-lab-nic1  --> vm-lab-nic1 ## Stays same ##
```

The delimiting characters are 'nic', 'a' only. Other combinations of "-" & characters should be kept intact.

How do I achieve the above using java regex ?

If possible, please suggest a single liner...

Comment: How were you able to do it with a multiple-line regex?

Comment: This doesn't look like splitting. It looks like removing suffixes. Perhaps you should provide your code as proper context.

Comment: If possible, please show your attempt

Comment: I've tried a few without success.. I'm a newbie in java.. I've tried this `(.?)[?:\-nic|\-adm]?`

Comment: You should show your attempted code/regex in question to get better help.

Comment: why you kept -new and -adm01? and which are possible suffixes ? also their lengths (looks 3 ..?)

Comment: @Marcos please edit your question with a list of suffixes you want removed. It looks like, at the moment, you want `-nic` and `-adm` removed. Are there any others?

Comment: I've edited to make the question more clear, but I'm open for more suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `String#replaceAll` method:

```
str = str.replaceAll("-(nic|a)\\b", "");
```

Regex `-(nic|adm)` matches a hyphen followed by `nic` or `adm`.

`\\b` is for word boundary to make sure we don't match unwanted text like `abc`.

You can add more suffixes in this group that you want to be removed.